# How can I show related model property in Django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have two models, **Retailer** and **Product** like this:

```
class Retailer(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description =  models.TextField(default=None, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=None, null=True)
    retailer = models.ForeignKey(Retailer,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='products')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.retailer) + ' - ' + str(self.price)
```

Now what I get is this:

[image]

But what I want is showing Retailer name instead of Retailer id in Django admin, what should I do?

Comment: ```self.retailer.name``` in your ```__str__```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have

```
class Retailer(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

change it to return the name, `return self.name` like this:

```
class Retailer(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

When you do `str(self.retailer)` it uses that function to figure out what to return. `str(self.retailer)` basically does `self.retailer.__str__()`